# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: angular, sass, find

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
2 │ @import "~@gbase/dt-theme/dt.theme";
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\styles.scss 2:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
2 │ @import "~@gbase/dt-theme/dt.theme";
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\styles.scss 2:9  root stylesheet

i am found this error message to the last 3 days and i try all the possible tricks but this error are not gone i try to upgrade my angular 14 project to angular 16 and i got this error so please help if you know how to solve this